# Issue with grid field and loading images, last image loaded keeps replacing all others

Tags: file-uploads, grid, image, files

I'm having an issue with loading images to the grid field from the file manager: I'll add a first row and image, and then add a 2nd row, and add a second image, the first image get's replaced by the 2nd image.  Then I'll add a 3rd row, and a 3rd image, and that image replaces all of the others.  Basically, the last image loaded replaces all of the others.  Weird.

I have a screencast showing this here: [screencast showing file/grid field issue](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By_mFRlykYSEa0ZTNUg1bVFZb1k/view)

Note/Edit: I tested with uploading new images to the file manager, and it does not occur when I do this, so it's just something with selecting images from the file manager? Screencast: [showing the issue doesn't occur with new files](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By_mFRlykYSETi10aWMtS21RZU0/view)

I've tried it with disabling extensions, same thing happens.

I don't have any errors in the console.

Any ideas what could be causing this?

ExpressionEngine v3.4.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just dealt with this myself today. Update your system to 3.4.2 and you're golden.